# Azure IMobileServiceTable change default route

Tags: c#, azure

I have a mobile app with a DTO called 'Delivery'. When I call `IMobileServiceTable.ToListAsync()`, this calls the method `GetAllDeliveries()` in my API controller named `DeliveryController`, i.e. it follows the naming convention of 'GetAll' in '[My DTO name]Controller'

I would like to have 2 different methods for `GetAllDeliveries()`, both with the same DTO, so I could use `ToListAsync()` to call either `GetAllDeliveries()` or `GetAllLatestDeliveries()`. I know I can change the routing in the backend, but is is possible to add an attribute to the DTO in the mobile app, so the IMobileServiceTable methods use different controller method names? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are able to specify a route by decorating the method with a 'Route' Attribute. [attribute routing MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

Comment: @OOPMichael, I know I can specify the route in the controller; what I want to do is specify in the mobile app, and not in the controller, which route the ToListAsync() method calls. If that is possible.

Comment: I don't believe so. you'll have to build the specific route you're referring to in the apicontroller.